# Как загрузить данные с сайта android

Tags: java, android

Есть ссылка:  http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN ,  нужно загрузить данные и вывести в лист.  Пробовал XmlPullParser и Jsoup, не получается, словно в ответ приходит пустой файл. Каким методом можно это сделать.

Вот код:

Main
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private final static String url = "http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN";
ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MenuParsTask(this, url).execute();

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_list);

    com.tolik23gmail.farfor.ListAdapter listAdapter = new com.tolik23gmail.farfor.ListAdapter(this,MenuParsTask.list);
    mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

}

Parser

```
public class MenuParsTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
public MainActivity activity;
private String url;
private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
public MenuParsTask(MainActivity activity, String url) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    pDialog.setTitle("Пожалуйста подождите.");
    pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка меню...");
    pDialog.show();
}


@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(this.url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(stream, null);
        ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) parseXML(parser);
        stream.close();

        return list;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}


public ArrayList<String> parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) {


    try {
        while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
                    && parser.getName().equals("category")) {

                String id = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                list.add(id);
            }
            parser.next();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list) {
    super.onPostExecute(list);
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Adapter

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by MaZ on 27.07.2016.
 */
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private List<String> mList;

public ListAdapter(Context context,List<String> list){
    this.mContext=context;
    this.mList=list;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}



static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_text;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList == null ? 0 : mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if(mList==null){
        return null;
    }
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.d("ListAdapter", "getView() position =" + position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tv_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.tv_text.setText(mList.get(position));

    return convertView;

}
```

}

Вроде как HttpURLConnection загружает пустой файл, так как пробовал вывести в log

```
public class ParsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
public MainActivity activity;
private String url;
private String text;
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
public ParsTask(MainActivity activity, String url) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    pDialog.setTitle(".......");
    pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
    pDialog.show();
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String cont;
    try{

        cont = getContent(url);
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        cont = ex.getMessage();
    }

    return cont;
}

private String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
    String res = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            res += line + "\n";
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... items) {
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String cont) {
    super.onPostExecute(cont);
    pDialog.dismiss();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"text="  + cont);
}
```

}

немного поправил в выводе, получилась вот так. Выводит совсем не по что по ссылке, а вот это

```js
D/myLogs: text=<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html lang="ru" class="page no-js"><head>    <meta charset="utf-8"/>            <title>Фарфор</title>        <meta name="description" content="">        <meta name="Keywords" content="">        <meta name="description" content="Закажите доставку суши за 1 час на дом и в офис по Уфе. Если мы не успеем доставить - подарим сет!">    <meta name="keywords" content="доставка суши Уфа заказ заказать фарфор быстро ресторан доставки дом офис">        <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/>    <meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir"/>    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o||e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({1:[function(t,e,n){function r(){}function o(t,e,n){return function(){return i(t,[(new Date).getTime()].concat(u(arguments)),e?null:this,n),e?void 0:this}}var i=t("handle"),a=t(2),u=t(3),c=t("ee").get("tracer"),f=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=f);var s=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit"],p="api-",l=p+"ixn-";a(s,function(t,e){f[e]=o(p+e,!0,"api")}),f.addPageAction=o(p+"addPageAction",!0),e.exports=newrelic,f.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var d=r.prototype={createTracer:function(t,e){var n={},r=this,o="function"==typeof e;return i(l+"tracer",[Date.now(),t,n],r),function(){if(c.emit((o?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[Date.now(),r,o],n),o)try{return e.apply(this,arguments)}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[Date.now()],n)}}}};a("setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(t,e){d[e]=o(l+e)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(t){"string"==typeof t&&(t=new Error(t)),i("err",[t,(new Date).getTime()])}},{}],2:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e){var n=[],r="",i=0;for(r in t)o.call(t,r)&&(n[i]=e(r,t[r]),i+=1);return n}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],3:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=t?t.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-e||0,i=Array(o<0?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[e+r];return i}e.exports=r},{}],ee:[function(t,e,n){function r(){}function o(t){function e(t){return t&&t instanceof r?t:t?u(t,a,i):i()}function n(n,r,o){t&&t(n,r,o);for(var i=e(o),a=l(n),u=a.length,c=0;c<u;c++)a[c].apply(i,r);var s=f[m[n]];return s&&s.push([w,n,r,i]),i}function p(t,e){g[t]=l(t).concat(e)}function l(t){return g[t]||[]}function d(t){return s[t]=s[t]||o(n)}function v(t,e){c(t,function(t,n){e=e||"feature",m[n]=e,e in f||(f[e]=[])})}var g={},m={},w={on:p,emit:n,get:d,listeners:l,context:e,buffer:v};return w}function i(){return new r}var a="nr@context",u=t("gos"),c=t(2),f={},s={},p=e.exports=o();p.backlog=f},{}],gos:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){if(o.call(t,e))return t[e];var r=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(i){}return t[e]=r,r}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n,r){o.buffer([t],r),o.emit(t,e,n)}var o=t("ee").get("handle");e.exports=r,r.ee=o},{}],id:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){var e=typeof t;return!t||"object"!==e&&"function"!==e?-1:t===window?0:a(t,i,function(){return o++})}var o=1,i="nr@id",a=t("gos");e.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(t,e,n){function r(){if(!h++){var t=y.info=NREUM.info,e=s.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(t&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&e){c(m,function(e,n){t[e]||(t[e]=n)});var n="https"===g.split(":")[0]||t.sslForHttp;y.proto=n?"https://":"http://"
```

ошибка

```html
07-28 11:08:25.645 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-7698/com.tolik23gmail.parserz E/Adreno200-ES20: <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1318>: **** 7698: glUseProgram(6)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-7698/com.tolik23gmail.parserz E/Adreno200-ES20: <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1318>: **** 7698: glUseProgram(3)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at com.tolik23gmail.parserz.ParsTask.getContent(ParsTask.java:125)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at com.tolik23gmail.parserz.ParsTask.doInBackground(ParsTask.java:55)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at com.tolik23gmail.parserz.ParsTask.doInBackground(ParsTask.java:25)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 11:08:25.665 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
07-28 11:08:25.675 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-28 11:08:25.675 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-28 11:08:25.675 7698-9303/com.tolik23gmail.parserz W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-28 11:08:25.675 7698-7698/com.tolik23gmail.parserz D/myLogs: text=
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897459/parsing-xml-from-website-to-an-android-device
Или же урок https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ErXzkAeuzQ

Comment: покажите что у вас есть

Comment: В вашем коде точно что-то не так. Вас устраивает такой ответ? Если нет, то покажите код.

Comment: @Senior Automator  выложил код

Comment: @metalurgus  выложил код

Comment: в манифесте android.permission.INTERNET выставлен?

Comment: @ravend да есть

Comment: @Lt_23 прокси не стоит случайно?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator извините не очень понимаю что это значит, где прокси может стоять?

Comment: @Lt_23 над сетью, где используешь. то есть прокси может не пускать ничего и поэтому ты ничего не можешь скачать.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator нет, другие ссылки работают

Comment: уберите `c.connect();` и пробуйте еще раз

Comment: @SeniorAutomator выводит тоже самое ( то что я выше скинул), какую то js строку

Comment: очень странно, потому что у меня выводит xml

Comment: @SeniorAutomator можно пожалуйста код посмотреть вывода?

Comment: @Lt_23 код такой же, как у тебя метод `private String getContent(String path)`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator то есть полностью мой код у вас работает? с асинктаск? или вы что то меняли? сбросте ваш рабочий код. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

как просил

```
    String res = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            res += line + "\n";
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
```

Comment: сделал как у вас, выдает ошибку код поменял в вопросе посмотрите, так же скинул текст ошибки